# Applying high pass filter on image in c#

Tags: c#, image-processing

After following [this](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/gradient/node1.html) article, I have come to know that high pass image can be achieved by subtracting low pass image from original image. I am first graying out the image and then applying following filter on the image (as explained in the article).

```
 return new int[,] {{-1, -2, -1},
                    {-2, 12, -2},
                    {-1, -2, -1}};
```

Right now just applying this filter, gives me an image detecting edges.

In [this](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/gradient/node1.html) article, it is suggested to **divide it by 16** after applying filter on the image. When I divide that i get an overflow exception and got a negative value to be stored in the image.

I need the following result

[image]

But I am getting this result

[image]

I need help in this, how can i get the first image.

Usually I divide the result by sum of filter array (in case of blurring the image).

This is the code for applying filter mask on the image..

```
  public static byte[,] applyFilterMask(byte[,] imageArray, int filterSize, int[,] filterMask, uint width, uint height)
    {
        byte[,] masked2DImage = new byte[height, width];
        for (int row = (filterSize/2) ; row < height - (filterSize/2); row++)
        {
            for (int col = (filterSize / 2); col < width - (filterSize / 2); col++)
            {
                int filterResult = 0;

                // these nested loops are to apply (generic) filter mask
                for (int filterRow = 0; filterRow < filterMask.GetLength(0); filterRow++)
                {
                    for (int filterColumn = 0; filterColumn < filterMask.GetLength(1); filterColumn++)
                    {
                        filterResult += imageArray[row - (filterSize/2) + filterRow, col - (filterSize/2) + filterColumn] * filterMask[filterRow, filterColumn];
                    }
                }

                filterResult = sumOfFilterMask(filterMask) == 0 ? filterResult : (filterResult / sumOfFilterMask(filterMask));
                filterResult = filterResult > 255 ? 255 : (filterResult < 0 ? 0 : filterResult);
                masked2DImage[row, col] = Convert.ToByte(filterResult);
            }
        }       

        return masked2DImage;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Quote from the article:

> Note that the sum of all elements of the resulting high-pass filter is
>   always zero.

Why do you want a gray background? Because you see one in the article?

The picture in the article is an image taken with a camera. Camera pictures always have noise. Hence you will hardly find any region that has the same gray value in a 9x9 neighbourhood. Small variations will lead to a non-black background.

Your image seems artificial. Some digital art that has no noise. The background is most likely of the same value. Therefor the filter result is zero and your result's background is black.

Answer (score 1):

The result of high-pass filter varies around zero, so, to make negative values visible they show 0+-values result as 128+-values in the image.

To get the same image you should initiate `filterResult` with 128

```
int filterResult = 128;
```

Comment: Hi, Can you explain a bit further? I didn't get your point. What changes should i make in my above code? Is it to check condition for 128 rather than 255?

Comment: No, I mean change 8th line from int filterResult = 0; to int filterResult = 128;